ROUNDED statement in COBOL
I need to write a code to round the 4 decimal data to 2 decimal data.
VAR-A PIC S9(15)V9(4) VALUE 1111.1294
VAR-B PIC S9(15)V99   VALUE ZERO.

when i MOVE VAR-A to VAR-B the expected value is 1111.13 instead i am getting 1111.12
Can someone kindly help on what I need to do.
I am using below statement.
MOVE VAR-A TO VAR-B


A MOVE doesn't round, it truncates.  Try ADD VAR-A TO VAR-B ROUNDED. Enterprise COBOL for z/OS

Hi, Thank you for the reply. But I am not able to use ADD statement since in my program VAR-B is having data which I am trying to override with VAR-A data. Its my mistake for not mentioning earlier that VAR-b is having data.

Then move zero to VAR-B before the ADD.

Yes I have did the same. It's worked. Thank you very much!!!

you can rounding by using the COMPUTE instruction.
COMPUTE VAR-B ROUNDED = VAR-A * 1
Have a nice day.

First of all, you are missing a period at the end of the definition of VAR-A. Given the correct syntax, the MOVE statement in cobol, basically truncates the data. I will show this with the following example:
VAR-A PIC S9(15)V9(04) VALUE 1111.1294.
VAR-B PIC S9(15)V9(02) VALUE ZERO.
...
MOVE VAR-A TO VAR-B.
DISPLAY VAR-B.

note that in the SYSOUT, the result of VAR-B will be shown as 1111.12. So the truncation eliminates the right-most digits which would not fit.
If you want to have a rounded version in the case of numbers; the following does the trick:
COMPUTE B ROUNDED = A

That is all. One last note, for people writing the code in Europe, as Europeans tend to use the comma for decimal separation, the number should be written as 1111,1294. But this again depends, on your CONFIGURATION SECTION in the ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. Should you have the following code snipped in your cobol source code:
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
CONFIGURATION SECTION.
SPECIAL-NAMES.
    DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA.

Then the number should be written as 1111,1294 but otherwise 1111.1294 will not cause an error by the compiler.
